# Convergence of operator-exponential

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

Let $T: [0,\infty) \rightarrow L(X)$ define a $C_0$ semigroup on a Banach space $X$, then I want to show that $A_h:=\frac{T(h)-id}{h}$ are such that $e^{tA_h}(f) \rightarrow T(t)(f)$ pointwise. Clearly, $A_h \in L(X),$ so that the exponential is defined, but I don't get the limit. Does anybody have an idea how this can be done?

Comment: Could you perhaps have intended to write $T: [0, \infty) \to \mathscr L(X)$, the space of bounded linear operators on $X$, rather than $T: [0, \infty) \to \Bbb R$?  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis you are right of course.

Comment: Suspected as much; thanks for the speedy reply!

Comment: Also, you want $e^{tA_h}(f) \rightarrow T(t)(f)$ as $h \to 0$, right?

Comment: yes, $h \rightarrow 0$ and $t$ is fixed.

Comment: OK, thanks again!